# Sinon.JS stub for window.location.search

Tags: coffeescript, stubbing, sinon, buster.js

I am trying to test a simple function that makes a call to window.location.search.  I'm trying to understand how to stub this call so that I can return a url of my choosing.

function:

```
getParameterByName: (name) =>    
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]")
  regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"
  regex = new RegExp(regexS)    
  results = regex.exec(window.location.search) //Stub call to window.location.search
  if(results == null)
    return ""
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "))
```

Test case:

```
describe "Data tests", () ->
  it "Should parse parameter from url", () ->        
    data = new Data()

    console.log("search string: " + window.location.search) //prints "search string:"
    window.location.search = "myUrl"
    console.log("search string: " + window.location.search) //prints "search string:"
    console.log(data.getParameterByName('varName'))

    expect(true).toBe(true)
```

My original attempt was to return a value directly like so:

```
sinon.stub(window.location.search).returns("myUrl")
```

This, of course, doesn't work. I don't think I'm specifying the stub correctly, but it shows my intent.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, as mentioned before, you can't mock window.location directly.  Nor did the mylib.search wrapper idea work with my situation.  So, what I did was break out my call to `window.location.search` into its own function.  My new class looks like so:

```
getParameterByName: (name) =>
  console.log("name: #{name}")
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]")
  regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"
  regex = new RegExp(regexS)
  results = regex.exec(@getWindowLocationSearch())
  if(results == null)
    return ""
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "))

getWindowLocationSearch:() =>
  window.location.search
```

Then in my test case, I replace the function with my test code like so:

```
describe "Data tests", () ->
  it "Should parse parameter from localhost url", () ->
    goodUrl = "http://localhost:3333/?token=val1"

    Data::getWindowLocationSearch = () -> return goodUrl
    unit = new Data()
    result = unit.getParameterByName("token")

    expect(result).toBe("val1")
```

For those who don't read Coffeescript, the equivalent javascript code is listed below:

```
it("Should parse parameter from localhost url", function() {
  var goodUrl, result, unit;
  goodUrl = "http://localhost:3333/?token=val1";
  Data.prototype.getWindowLocationSearch = function() {
    return goodUrl;
  };
  unit = new Data();
  result = unit.getParameterByName("token");
  expect(result).toBe("val1");
  return expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

As is my usual experience with Javascript.  The working solution was not nearly as painful as the journey to get there.  Thank you very much for your comments and contributions.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: `window.location`, it seems, is a bit of a special case, see this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sinonjs/MMYrwKIZNUU%5B1-25%5D

The easiest way to solve this problem is to write a wrapper function around `window.location`, and stub that:

```
mylib.search = function (url) {
  window.location.search = url;
};
```

And in your test:

```
sinon.stub(mylib, 'search').returns("myUrl")
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Try this:

```
sinon.stub(window.location, 'search').returns("myUrl")
```

Comment: I've tried that one before and I just tried it again: `TypeError: Attempted to wrap string property search as function`

Comment: oh sorry, `window.location.search` is a string not a function, so you can't stub it. Replace the stub with an assignment: `window.location.search = "myUrl"`.

Comment: Weird, performing a console.log before and after results in a blank string so I'm not sure what's going on. The assignment isn't sticking. I updated my code to show my test case as well.

Comment: ok, I think this is actually harder than I originally thought. See this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sinonjs/MMYrwKIZNUU%5B1-25%5D

Comment: This didn't work on my class since I had to use prototype to overide the function.  Sinon's stub would not work with my class because of this.